Session persistence in oracle apex
in oracle apex, how to implement auto-login in a new window:

When a user logs in, store their APEX_SESSION_ID securely (e.g., in a browser cookie or local storage).
When opening a new window, retrieve this stored APEX_SESSION_ID.
Use the APEX_SESSION_ID to authenticate the user in the new window.

I tried using javascript, pl/sql code, But i did not get correct approach

APEX manages session IDs on its own., generating new ones periodically. You can't copy them like that as far as I know. The session_id isn't what authenticates the user, regardless. The nature of authentication will depend on your specific architecture and application authentication definition. Details are generally stored in cookies or in HTTP headers. What problem are you trying to solve here?

I think what you should look for is SSO

You should not store the session id but the username. Sessions expire and are cleaned up by APEX automatically. There are a couple of old blogs about this subject, I found them by googling the term "oracle apex logon with cookie". This is a great example, it also has a link in it to a similar blog
